# Extract data from a .vtk unstructured grid file and convert them into .txt or .csv files

Tags: vtk, paraview

Using the Paraview application, I would like to extract data from a .vtk unstructured grid file and convert this data into .txt or .csv files. In the file menu, I have tested `Save Data`  but I obtain a .csv file with one column "Cell Type" containing only the value 9. How can I get the data in a .txt or .csv file ? My .vtk file contains 9 variables and for each variable, I have data at each time step.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your dataset contains only PointsData, not CellData. Make sure to Select :

- "Point Association : Point"

when saving the data as a .csv file.